# Dealing with a pair of nullable foreign keys which could "logically" be part of the identity

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but here goes. A bit of background:

I'm designing a system where users will select fields with a specified order. These fields are associated to a profile. The fields are selected from 2 different tables, one with system fields, and one with custom fields. Those fields would be stored in a table, but the original design actually does not define any schema relations between the field tables and the mapping table.

I want to actually map the 2 different tables properly, but I'm hitting a wall with how the mapping table should be defined. Here's the original design and what seems "logical" to me.

[image]

How do I construct this mapping table? I feel like the foreign keys should be used as primary keys, but obviously each row would either have a nullable **CustomFieldId** or **FieldId**, making this impossible.

Do I give up on having the foreign keys as primary keys and add uniqueness constraints in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are missing an extra relation (table) here.**

What you have is a *polymorphic association*, where you have a concept of a `Field`, which can either be a `SystemField` or a `CustomField`. There are a number of ways to do this, for example you could just use a `bit` flag, but a common one is to separate them into different tables, and use the `Id` of the base table along with a `Type` as both the PK of the child tables, and the foreign key back to `Field`.

Now you can simply have `ProfileFields` refer to the base table, it does not need to worry about which type a `Field` is.

**What you need then are the following tables (pseudo-code):**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Field (
  Id int IDENTITY,
  FieldType char(1) CHECK (FieldType IN ('S', 'C')),
  PRIMARY KEY (Id, FieldType),
 ...)
-- this represents any type of field

CREATE TABLE SystemField (
  Id int,   -- no IDENTITY
  FieldType char(1) CHECK (FieldType = 'S'),
  PRIMARY KEY (Id, FieldType),
  FOREIGN KEY (Id, FieldType) REFERENCES Field (Id, FieldType),
...)

CREATE TABLE CustomField (
  Id int,   -- no IDENTITY
  FieldType char(1) CHECK (FieldType = 'C'),
  PRIMARY KEY (Id, FieldType),
  FOREIGN KEY (Id, FieldType) REFERENCES Field (Id, FieldType),
...)

CREATE TABLE Profile ( .... )

CREATE TABLE ProfileFields (
  ProfileId int,
  FieldId int,
  FieldType char(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (ProfileId, FieldId, FieldType),
  FOREIGN KEY (ProfileId) REFERENCES Profile (Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (FieldId, FieldType) REFERENCES Field (Id, FieldType),
...)
```

**Note that `ProfileFields` does not reference the two child tables.**

You add a field by first adding to `Field`, then taking its `IDENTITY` value and adding it to the relevant table:

```
INSERT Field (FieldType, ...)
VALUES ('S', ... );

INSERT SystemField (Id, FieldType, ...)
VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'S', ... );
```

You could potentially remove `FieldType` from `ProfileFields` but then you would need a second unique key on `Id` in the base `Field` table.

You can also change the `CHECK` constraint into a lookup table, but I personally don't see the point.

Comment: That is quite an ingenious way to solve the problem. I was thinking that there might be a table missing, but I didn't know how to differentiate between the two tables. Adding a type in the child tables to be used  as a foreign key is not intuitive , but it makes total sense. Thank you very much for the very thorough solution!